# Group by based on where clause

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate

This is my input data

```
Num             Type          Code
121526s206      FFSv          2
121526s206      MEDI          3
121526s206      MEDI          4
```

This is my query -

```
select num, code, count(*)
from pay
where code = 
      case when code = '1' then '1'
      when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then '1'
      when code = '2' then '2' 
      when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' ) then '2'
end
group by num, code
```

My current output is below. It has this one record because there is one `code` `2` in the input data.

```
Num          Code     Count
121526s206   2        1
```

How do I get this output -

```
Num          Code     Count
121526s206   2        2
```

I am wanting the count to be `2` because I want code `2` to include all records where the code is 2 and all records where the `code` is `3` and type is in `( 'MGD', 'MEDI' )`.

Comment: Change order of conditions in the CASE as it is important

Comment: Why do you want code=2 in the results since you are also counting code=3?

Comment: @VitalyBorisov I don't think CASE is the way to solve this problem since I want both multiple CASE statements to be true.

Comment: @forpas I want to count `code` `3` where `type` is `MGD` or `MEDI` as code `2`, not as code `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by num and a CASE expression which will change the code to fit your conditions:

```
select num, 
  case 
    when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then '1'
    when code = '3' AND type IN ('MGD', 'MEDI') then '2'
    else code 
  end code, 
  count(*) counter
from pay
group by num, 
  case 
    when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then '1'
    when code = '3' AND type IN ('MGD', 'MEDI') then '2'
    else code 
  end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0503948bf3d4b26e65a0db7cfaac556d) (for SQL Server but it is standard SQL).
Results:

```
> num        | code | counter
> :--------- | ---: | ------:
> 121526s206 |    2 |       2
> 121526s206 |    4 |       1
```

For Mysql the code can be simplified by simply aliasing the result of the CASE expression:

```
select num, 
  case 
    when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then '1'
    when code = '3' AND type IN ('MGD', 'MEDI') then '2'
    else code 
  end newcode, 
  count(*) counter
from pay
group by num, newcode
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pQxTNCZ276HVECCSMRdXbC/0).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Can you please explain your answer.

Comment: The CASE expression returns a new Code based on your conditions. So when `when code = '3' AND type IN ('MGD', 'MEDI')` returns the code as `2` and not as `3` and the grouping and counting is based on this new Code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the case in the select part like this:

```
select Code,  sum(case when code = 1 then 1
      when code = 3 AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then 1
      when code = 2 then 2 
      when code = 3 AND type IN ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' ) then 2
      else 0 
end) as _Count  
from pay 
group by code having sum(case when code = 1 then 1
      when code = 3 AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then 1
      when code = 2 then 2 
      when code = 3 AND type IN ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' ) then 2
      else 0 
end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.num, t.code, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  select num, 
      case when code = '1' then '1'
        when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'FED', 'ASST', 'MED' ) then '1'
        when code = '2' then '2' 
        when code = '3' AND type IN ( 'MGD', 'MEDI' ) then '2'
        ELSE code
      end AS code
  from pay) t
group by t.num, t.code
```